# Why doesn't cut command split a given string?

Tags: echo, cut

Cut works as expected here

```
$ cat test 
1;2;3;4
$ cut -d ';' -f 2 test 
2
$ cut -d ';' -f 3 test 
3
```

But I would expect it to output '21' here, what am I doing wrong?

```
$ updates=""
$ echo "$updates" | cat -v

$ updates=$(/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check 2>&1);echo $updates
21;0
$ echo "$updates" | cat -v
21;0
$ updates=""
$ updates=$(/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check 2>&1);echo $updates | 
cut -d ";" -f 1
21
$ echo "$updates" | cat -v
21;0
```

When I try Stéphanes solution

```
$ cat test2.sh 
updates=$(/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check)
all=${updates%";"*}
security=${updates#*";"}
printf '%s\n' "$all packages can be updated" \
          "$security updates are security updates"
$ ./test2.sh 
21;0 packages can be updated
updates are security updates
```

Comment: What is the value of `$updates` (echo it without running that `apt-check` thing (I'm not sure what that has to do with anything))?

Comment: My suspicion is that there’s a carriage return or other non-printing characters in the variable.

Comment: I'd agree with Kusalananda and Jeff. Can you [edit] the question to include the output of `echo "$updates" | cat -v`?

Comment: It looks like the value of the `updates` variable has changed since running the `cut` command. You should show the output of the `cut` command directly after displaying its contents with `cat -v`. Also, the output is a lot more readable if you redact the `joey@tower-ix:~/scripts/testing` from the prompt.

Comment: Are you somehow expecting `(/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check)` to magically set the `$updates` variable of your shell?

Comment: opps I dident catch that in all my copy pasting, I was missing " 2>&1" let me retest...thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To assign the standard output and standard error of a command (minus the trailing newline characters) to a variable, the syntax in POSIX-like shells is:

```
updates=$(/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check 2>&1)
```

To output the content of a variable with an added newline character, the syntax is:

```
printf '%s\n' "$updates"
```

To split the content of a variable on a character, the syntax is:

```
IFS=';'
set -o noglob
set -- $updates

printf '%s\n' "First element: $1" "Second element: $2"
```

Or you can do:

```
updates=$(/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check 2>&1)
all=${updates%";"*}
security=${updates#*";"}
printf '%s\n' "$all packages can be updated" \
              "$security updates are security updates"
```

To get an equivalent of

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable
```

You can also use `cut` to get the first semi-colon delimited field of each line of a variable with:

```
printf '%s\n' "$updates" | cut -d ';' -f 1
```

Though if that variable has only one line, it's a bit overkill.

Comment: Thanks, see edit I pasted the output. It still combines both security and all

Comment: @sealfab. Sorry, my bad. I hadn't realised that `apt-check` was printing its output on stderr (pretty silly of them if you ask me as that means you can't easily separate it from error messages!). See edit.

Comment: thanks that works, now I understand ">&" and standard streams better